# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzuw;

Tags: react-native

My app is successfully build but unable to open my app its getting crashed.  I checked the logcat and saw below mention error.

My android/gradle.build file contains classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' and classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzuw;
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlx.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlx.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.sbugert.rnadmob.RNAdMobInterstitialAdModule.<init>(RNAdMobInterstitialAdModule.java:48)
            at com.sbugert.rnadmob.RNAdMobPackage.createNativeModules(RNAdMobPackage.java:18)
            at com.facebook.react.NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.processPackage(NativeModuleRegistryBuilder.java:106)
            at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:1171)
            at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackages(ReactInstanceManager.java:1141)
            at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1083)
            at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$900(ReactInstanceManager.java:113)
            at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:920)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzuw
            at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 12 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzuy;
            ... 12 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzuy
            at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 12 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzev;
            ... 12 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzev" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sixdee.marketplace-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sixdee.marketplace-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.sixdee.marketplace-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 12 more
```

Heres My android/app/gradle.build :

```
   dependencies {
        implementation(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
            transitive = false
        }
        implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
        implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
        implementation project(':react-native-admob')
        implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
        implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')
        implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
        implementation project(':react-native-blur')
        implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
        implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
        implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
        implementation project(':react-native-geocoder')
        implementation project(':react-native-image-resizer')
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4.22.1)'

        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'

        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
        implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.54.4"){force = true}
        //compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Sometimes, this problem occurred when you have conflict dependencies vesion

try to run `./gradlew app:dependencies` in `/android` dir

That command will print all dependencies in your app. From that, you can figure out, whether any dependencies version is conflict